# Как спрятать ползунок громкости?

Tags: java, android, ui

Я разрабатываю приложение под Android, в котором мне нужно использовать кнопки громкости как элемент управления. Я успешно получаю значение громкости с помощью AudioManager внутри фрагмента, всё работает, но есть одна единственная проблема, решения которой я пока не нашел.

При нажатии на кнопки громкости на экране появляется системный ползунок громкости (совершенно ожидаемо). Он мешает, и я хотел бы каким-либо образом сделать его невидимым, или сделать так, чтобы конкретно в этом приложении он не вызывался.

Можно ли это сделать через код Java?

Comment: Не совсем понятна суть вопроса, вам нужно перехватить нажатия кнопок? Вроде вы пишете, что хотите использовать кнопки как элемент управления, но зачем вам тогда считывать значение громкости?

Comment: Понял, видимо вы нашли обходной способ, но все решается гораздо проще, посмотрите [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1307925).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы перехватить нажатия на кнопки громкости, в активити переопределите метод `onKeyDown` и обработайте кейкоды [`KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) и [`KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN):

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Volume Up!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Volume Down!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: Это именно то, что мне нужно! Спасибо.